# Probability of getting a rational number for continuum trials

Tags: probability, measure-theory

As far as I know, the probability of getting a rational number from the interval $(0, 1)$ is zero if we follow the Lebesgue measure. Still, it doesn't mean it's impossible.

Now, suppose we have a continuum number of independent random variables $X_{\alpha}$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Each of them is a sample from the interval $(0, 1)$. Would then the probability of getting at least one rational be positive?

Comment: Hi: No. the union of events, each of which has lebesgue measure zero,  is still zero.  ir's analogous to the uniform distribution. Suppose a variable X has a uniform distribution over (0,1). The probability that X = x is zero. But if you generate a uniform random variable, x's are created. Think of the probability being so small that it's zero mathematically. But if you start adding them up, the zero-ness goes away.

Comment: @mlofton Your initial statement is incorrect. Let $U$ have a Uniform$(0,1)$ distribution and for each $x\in(0,1)$ let $E_x=\{x\}.$ These events all have probability zero, yet their union is $\bigcup_{x\in(0,1)} E_x = (0,1),$ which has probability $1.$

Comment: @mlofton: *countable* unions of zero sets have zero measure. The interesting aspect here is that we haven an *uncountable* union.

Comment: whuber: thanks for heads up. I was el wrongo. Stephan: Thanks for pointing out where I erred. I like to say that I intended to say countable but I didn't :).

Comment: @StephanKolassa I found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure. Does this mean that sequence $X_{\alpha}$ with assumptions stated as in my question doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

This set of random variables can be considered as a function $f:\alpha \to X_\alpha$. So the question is what is $P(\exists \alpha | f(\alpha) is rational)$.

When the question is put this way, you can see that it relies on having a probability measure on the space of possible functions. The question, if asked for any "continuum number of random variables", is unanswerable.

If the set of possible functions is the constant functions (with the natural measure), then the answer is zero. But with many natural sets of functions the answer is one, since any nonconstant continuous function has some rationals in its image.

Comment: Is there any canonical way of defining a measure on such functions? I mean, something like product measure on $\Omega = (0, 1)^n$, which is $\mu(A_1 \times A_2 \times \cdots \times A_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\mu(A_i)$, but for $\Omega = (0, 1)^{\mathbb{R}}$?

Comment: Not really. L2 is a popular measure space over functions, but there are others. Which you use depends on context.